# Как восстановить инфу из sessionStorage при выполнении определенных условий?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет. Есть селектор со своей структурой с динамическим содержимым, которое не сохраняется при обновлении/перезагрузке страницы Сохраняю его при помощи sessionStorage. Как восстановить его содержимое при обновлении страницы при наличии определенного содержимого в `.foot-carousel div` ?

Подправил код. в `sessionStorage` сохраняет список, который хочу потом динамически выводить в карусель, а сам список скрывать, но вот это строчка пока еще не работает, до нее не доходит `$('#foot-carousel').data('owlCarousel').addItem('<div class="li">...</div>');`

```js
var field = $("#fix-bot");
console.log(field);

if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave")) {
  field.html(sessionStorage.getItem("autosave"));
  console.log("Load autosaved value");
}

field.on("change", function() {
  sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", field.html());
  console.log("change");
});

$('#change').on('click', function() {

  if ($(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").hasClass("empty")) {} else {

    $('#foot-carousel').find('>').remove()

    $('.fixed-bottom .cart_list li').each(function() {
      if ($(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").hasClass("empty")) {} else {
        $('#foot-carousel').data('owlCarousel').addItem('<div class="li">...</div>');
      };
    });
  };
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<div class="fixed-bottom" id="fix-bot">
  <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget "></ul>
  <!-- end product list -->
  <div id="foot-carousel" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="empty"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _определенное содержимое в `#foot-carousel div`_ - это какое содержимое?

Comment: Перефразируйте вопрос. Вы вроде как написали код, который вроде как делает то что вам надо. В чем именно проблема?

Comment: @Regent в `#foot-carousel div` содержимое элементов в виде html-структуры или нужно подробнее ?

Comment: @Constantine Pl как перефразировать? в sessionStorage я сохраняю html содержимое элементов, но ведь при перезагрузке его нужно как-то извлечь - правильно? или sessionStorage само его извлекает?

Comment: Вы сохраняете `.innerHTML` в виде строки в `sessionStorage`. Затем вы загружаете `.innerHTML` из строки из `sessionStorage`. Всё работает. В чём проблема? Вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/5q3q79Lo/).

Comment: @Regent а ну понятно - значит как всегда это просто у меня не выводит, но не будем углубляться в детали - это не тема этого вопроса. единственное уточнение, если хочу, чтобы срабатывало при определенных условиях - нужно условие вывода менять здесь - верно? `if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave")) {}`

Comment: Да, если хотите, чтобы HTML-код восстанавливался из `sessionStorage` только при выполнении доп. условий, стоит в этот `if` добавить эти условия. И, по традиции: важно своевременно сохранять и загружать данные, а также постоянно следить за тем, чтобы никакой другой код не ломал логику.

Comment: @Regent как я понял и вижу через консоль sessionStorage в innerHTML мое динамическое содержимое (моей карусели) не сохраняет, только статику

Comment: @Вася сохраняется тот HTML-код, который есть внутри элемента на момент сохранения.

Comment: @Regent да, а на динамически получаемый контент не реагирует. как сохранил объект с пустым списком, так и все осталось на своих местах, т.е. `field.addEventListener("change", function() {..}` не отрабатывает..

Comment: @Вася так а вы вызываете событие `change`? В моём коде `.trigger('change')` есть.

Comment: @Regent так, уже кое-что стало получаться - по крайней мере сохранение проходит. буду докручивать - пытаюсь уловить разницу между вашим и моим кодом..

Comment: @Regent в вопросе код поправил - вот так вызываю  событие `change` - правильно или нет?

Comment: @Вася `.trigger('change')` в вашем коде исполняется всего один раз - при добавлении обработчика `click` и для элемента `$('#change')`. Поместите `field.trigger('change');` в конце обработчика `click` - не знаю, то ли это, что вам надо, но это хотя бы выглядит логично. Вот про это изучение я и говорил.

Comment: фуух!.. все получилось, но по другой причине - удалось разыскать код, который отвечает за генерацию мини корзины `mini-cart.php` весь скрипт туда перенес и наконец-то заработало! как мне @Regent еще с самого начала советовал - Спасибо большое!теперь займусь оптимизацией. вопрос закрыт

Comment: @Вася на здоровье. Вопрос в таком случае можно удалять.

Comment: @Regent это не в моей компетенции, но с моей т. зр. здесь есть полезные моменты для ознакомления и понимания

Comment: @Вася если вы считаете его полезным для других - не удаляйте. А вообще - кнопка-строка _Удалить_ под метками вопроса есть.

Answer (score 1):

@Regent показал то, что хранится в autosave после перезагрузки. Притом `$('.fixed-bottom .cart_list li').each(function(){..)` после `field.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");` не выполняется - не знаю, так должно ли быть?

```js
var field = document.getElementById("fix-bot");
console.log(field);

// Проверяем, что значение поля autosave существует
// (это будет происходить при случайной перезагрузке страницы)
if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave")) {
  // Восстановить значение тестового поля
  field.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
  $('.fixed-bottom .cart_list li').each(function() {
    if ($(".fixed-bottom .cart_list li").hasClass("empty")) {} else {
      $('#foot-carousel').data('owlCarousel').addItem('<div class="li"></div>');
    };
  });

  $('.li').each(function() {});
  $(".fixed-bottom").show().fadeTo("slow");
  console.log("autosave");
}

// Прослушивать изменения значения текстового поля
field.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // И сохранить результаты в объект хранилища сессий
  sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", field.innerHTML);
  console.log("change");
});
```

```html
<!-- То, что показывает autosave в консоли, притом, что в ul содержимое есть, а в owl-carousel оно пропадает -->
<div class="fixed-bottom" id="fix-bot">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 cart-carusel">
        <h3>ДОБАВЛЕННЫЕ БЛЮДА</h3>
        <div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
          <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget ">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <img width="60" height="60" src="#" class="attachment-60x60 wp-post-image" alt="item-2">
              </a>
              <div class="product-text">..</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- end product list -->

        </div>
        <div id="foot-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
          <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
            <div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 630px; left: 0px; display: block;">
              <div class="owl-item" style="width: 315px;">
                <div class="empty"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-controls clickable" style="display: none;">
            <div class="owl-buttons">
              <div class="owl-prev"></div>
              <div class="owl-next"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```